# In PyAutoGUI using the region keyword argument throws off "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object"

Tags: python-3.x, pyautogui

This works properly...

`pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('~/file-01.png', confidence=0.6)`

but this...

`pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('~/file-01.png', region=(100,675,1400,600), confidence=0.6)`

returns `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object` despite the button I want to click on in `~/file-01.png` being within the region.

[The Locate Functions](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/screenshot.html#the-locate-functions) links to the PyAutoGUI man page that explains how to use the optional `region` keyword argument.